# How to serve Kubernetes backend and Firebase hosting frontend from the same domain name?

Tags: firebase, kubernetes, firebase-hosting, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-cdn

I want to setup web app using three components that i already have:

1. Domain name registered on domains.google.com
2. Frontend web app hosted on Firebase Hosting and served from `example.com`
3. Backend on Kubernetes cluster behind Load Balancer with external static IP `1.2.3.4`

I want to serve the backend from `example.com/api` or `api.example.com`

My best guess is to use Cloud DNS to connect IP adress and subdomain (or URL)

- `1.2.3.4` -> `api.exmple.com`
- `1.2.3.4` -> `example.com/api`

The problem is that Cloud DNS uses custom name servers, like this:

```
ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com
```

So if I set Google default name servers I can reach Firebase hosting only, and if I use custom name servers I can reach only Kubernetes backend.

What is a proper way to be able to reach both api.example.com and example.com?

edit:
As a temporary workaround i'm combining two default name servers and two custom name servers from cloud DNS, like this:

- `ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com` (custom)
- `ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com` (custom)
- `ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com` (default)
- `ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com` (default)

But if someone knows the proper way to do it - please post the answer.

Comment: I am not entirely sure but have you explored using an `ExternalName` service pointing to firebase & then ingress controller in Kubernetes pointing to Firebase using that service and backend using another service.

Comment: Interesting, I need to think about this, thanks. My first concern about this approach is that I will pay twice for firebase cdn AND kubernetes ingress traffic. And I will need to figure something out for SSL certificates because in my current solution Firebase has free "real" SSL and Kubernetes has self-signed SSL for ingress and of course user should not face "not secure" certificate in browser.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1:**

```
example.com --> Firebase Hosting (A record)
api.example.com --> Kubernetes backend
```

Pro: Super-simple

Con: CORS request needed by browser before API calls can be made.

**Approach 2:**

```
example.com --> Firebase Hosting via k8s ExternalName service
example.com/api --> Kubernetes backend
```

Unfortunately from my own efforts to make this work with service `type: ExternalName` all I could manage is to get infinitely redirected, something which I am still unable to debug.

**Approach 3:**

```
example.com --> Google Cloud Storage via NGINX proxy to redirect paths to index.html
example.com/api --> Kubernetes backend
```

You will need to deploy the static files to Cloud Storage, with an NGINX proxy in front if you want SPA-like redirection to index.html for all routes. This approach does not use Firebase Hosting altogether.

The complication lies in the /api redirect which depends on which Ingress you are using.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating two host paths. The first would be going to "example.com" using NodePort type. You can then use the [External Name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname) service for "api.exmple.com".